# Iterating through a list with a different type

Tags: c#, foreach, interface

I came across something unusual when trying to iterate through lists using a different type. I have some example code below.

I am using two interfaces:

```
interface IViewable
{
    void View();
}

interface IHideable
{
    void Hide();
}
```

And the following classes:

```
class AwesomeClass : IViewable, IHideable
{
    public void Hide()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Le hiding.");
    }

    public void View()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Le toucan has arrived.");
    }
}

class LessAwesomeClass : IViewable
{
    public void View()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Le arrival.");
    }
}
```

*Note: LessAwesomeClass does **not** inherit IHideable*

Here is an example console application that uses these:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<IViewable> viewable = new List<IViewable>();

        viewable.Add(new AwesomeClass());
        viewable.Add(new LessAwesomeClass());

        //This runs fine.
        foreach (IViewable view in viewable)
            view.View();

        //Oh no! InvalidCastException
        foreach (IHideable hidable in viewable)
            hidable.Hide();

        Console.Read();
    }
```

When attempting to iterate through the list where the type is `IHideable`, it throws an InvalidCastException. This makes sense, as it's clearly trying to cast the item to `IHideable`. I understand this.

Now the problem here is that the application **compiles**. Which I think is a bit odd.

This is what confused me, as I was writing this and was thinking, "Hey! I can do a for each loop for IHideable and **filter out** anything that isn't IHideable, great! Oh wait, InvalidCastException."

So the first question is **why does this compile**?
And the second question, is there a way to *filter out* everything that isn't `IHideable` when doing a foreach loop?

Either way, it probably isn't a good idea to do this, it was more of a "I wonder if this will work" situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why does this compile?

[EricLippert answers it here](http://ericlippert.com/2013/07/22/why-does-a-foreach-loop-silently-insert-an-explicit-conversion/)

> Is there a way to filter out everything that isn't IHideable when
>   doing a foreach loop?

Yes, use [OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension method.

```
foreach (IHideable hidable in viewable.OfType<IHideable>())
    hidable.Hide();
```